# How can I get the FTP URL for my Azure website via the Management API?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-marketplace, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get my Azure Web Site's FTP upload address from the Management REST API. Looking at the source code for the [Azure SDK Tools](http://github.com/windowsazure/azure-sdk-tools), I don't see anything that could help me out, save for a web site property that would be sent via the GetSite action on [IWebsitesServiceManagement](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/blob/master/WindowsAzurePowershell/src/Management.WebSites/Services/IWebsitesServiceManagement.cs). Has anyone encountered this problem, and figured out how to get this going?

Edit: clarification and links.

Comment: I wonder how can you accept an answer which is not real answer. The question is exactly `via Management API`. And as it was back in December, it is also today - you cannot do it `via Management API`. How can you accept an answer which points you to use the browser?

Comment: @astaykov: Using his information I was able to use the REST call that returned the FTP address. While it's hardly elegant, it works. If you prefer, I can generalize the question, which is "how can I programatically find the FTP address for a given site?"

Comment: Could you share the REST call you are making to get out the FTP Address, because it is still unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there already http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn166996.aspx. Still not available from Powershell, but at least API in place.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is no longer active.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the portal, you cna download a publishsettings file with this info.  There is also a link to the ftp address on the 'Dashboard' page for your site.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official documentation (not even "preview" documentation) on that subject. When you develop Management API tools, you should refer to [the online documentation for it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx). Given that this service (Web Sites) is in Preview, the API may change in any given moment, so I would not invest time in something, that is not even documented. It is waste of time.