# Publishing WebSite to Azure via powershell with SetParameters.xml

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment

Is there a chance how to use a SetParameters.xml file to set parameters in a web deployment package?

I would like to deploy an application by powershell script with cmdlets

- Select-AzureSubscription
- Publish-AzureWebsiteProject

But I have not found how to set a SetParameters.xml file to the Publish-AzureWebsiteProject cmdlet.
Or is there an another way? Processing the SetParameters.xml file into the web deployment package before calling the Publish-AzureWebsiteProject cmdlet?

Answer (score 3):

Publish-AzureWebsiteProject does not support SetParameters.xml.
The best I found is to use MSDeploy.exe. How to set arguments is in answers at [How can I get the PublishUrl via Azure PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893008/how-can-i-get-the-publishurl-via-azure-powershell)